Entity has null value in field with a relation, even though the foreign key is set
I have been working on my first API, and I run into a problem. I have a model of MyUser and Team, which has info on its members through decomposed many to many relation (which is not essential in this case) and one two many relation between Team and MyUser entities, where team has one leader, but a user can be a leader of many teams. When I create a team object with a foreign key and add to the database, when its loaded from it the value of the field MyUser Leader in null while the value of Guid LeaderId is not, which is weird and confusing. What could be a cause for such a behaviour?
Some source code:
MyUser model:
public class MyUser
{
    public MyUser(string userName, string email, string password)
    {
        Id = Guid.Empty;
        UserName = userName;
        Email = email;
        Password = password;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; init; }
    public string UserName { get; init; }
    public string Email { get; init; }
    public string Password { get; init; }

    public IList<MembershipRecord>? MembershipRecords { get; set; }
    public IList<Team>? OwnedTeams { get; set; }
}

And configuration:
public class MyUserConfigurations : IEntityTypeConfiguration<MyUser>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MyUser> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id)
            .IsClustered(false);
        builder.Property(x => x.Id).HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()");

        builder.HasMany(x => x.MembershipRecords)
            .WithOne(x => x.Member)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.MemberId)
            .IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

        builder.HasMany(x => x.OwnedTeams)
            .WithOne(x => x.Leader)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.LeaderId)
            .IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

        builder.Property(x => x.UserName)
            .HasMaxLength(40)
            .IsRequired();
        builder.Property(x => x.Email)
            .HasMaxLength(400)
            .IsRequired();
        builder.Property(x => x.Password)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired();
    }
}

Team model:
public class Team
{
    public Team(string name,string? description,Guid leaderId)
    {
        Id = Guid.Empty;
        Name = name;
        Description = description;
        LeaderId = leaderId;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; init; }
    public string Name { get; init; }
    public string? Description { get; init; }

    public Guid LeaderId { get; set; }
    public MyUser Leader { get; set; }

    public IList<MembershipRecord>? MembershipRecords { get; set; }
}

And configuration:
public class TeamConfigurations : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Team>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Team> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id)
            .IsClustered(false);
        builder.Property(x => x.Id).HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()");

        builder.HasOne(x => x.Leader)
            .WithMany(x => x.OwnedTeams)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.LeaderId)
            .IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

        builder.HasMany(x => x.MembershipRecords)
            .WithOne(x => x.Team)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.TeamId)
            .IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

        builder.Property(x=>x.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(40);
        builder.Property(x => x.Description)
            .HasMaxLength(1000);
    }
}

And finally, TeamsController:
[Route("teams")]
public class TeamsController : Controller
{
    TeamsRepository teamRepository;
    MyUsersRepository usersRepository;

    public TeamsController(VeddsContext context)
    {
        this.teamRepository = new TeamsRepository(context);
        this.usersRepository = new MyUsersRepository(context);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetTeams()
    {
        var task = teamRepository.GetTeams();

        var data = await task;

        return Ok(data);
    }

    [HttpGet("{id:guid}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetTeamWithId(Guid id)
    {
        var task = teamRepository.GetTeamById(id);

        var data = await task;

        if (data == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(data);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("search")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SearchTeamWithName(string userName = "")
    {
        var task = teamRepository.SearchTeamsByName(userName);

        var data = await task;

        return Ok(data);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{teamId:guid}/leader")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetLeader(Guid teamId)
    {
        var task = teamRepository.GetTeamById(teamId);
        var data = await task;

        if (data == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var task2 = teamRepository.GetLeader(teamId);
        var data2 = await task2;

        return Ok(data2);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{teamId:guid}/members/")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetMembers(Guid teamId)
    {
        var task = teamRepository.GetTeamById(teamId);
        var data = await task;

        if (data == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var task2 = teamRepository.GetMembers(teamId);
        var data2 = await task2;

        return Ok(data2);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] Team team)
    {
        var task = usersRepository.GetUserById(team.LeaderId);
        var leader = await task;

        if (leader == null)
        {
            return NotFound("User for the leader role has nor been found");
        }

        await teamRepository.AddTeam(team.Name, team.Description, leader.Id);
        return Ok();
    }
}

Edit: this is the TeamsRepository code:
public class TeamsRepository
{
    private VeddsContext context;

    public TeamsRepository(VeddsContext context)
    {
        this.context= context;
    }

    public async Task<IList<Team>> GetTeams()
    {
        return await context.Teams.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<Team?> GetTeamById(Guid id)
    {
        var query = context.Teams
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(x => x.Id == id);

        return await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    public async Task<IList<Team>> SearchTeamsByName(string name)
    {
        var query = context.Teams
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(x => x.Name.Contains(name));

        return await query.ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<MyUser?> GetLeader(Guid id)
    {
        var query = context.Teams
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where (x => x.Id == id)
            .Select(x => x.Leader);

        return await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    } 

    public async Task<IList<MyUser>?> GetMembers(Guid id)
    {
        Team? team = await context.Teams
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(x => x.Id == id)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        if(team == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var query = context.Teams.
            AsNoTracking()
            .Where(t => t.Id == team.Id)
            .Join(context.MembershipRecords, t => t.Id, m => m.TeamId, (t,m)=>m)
            .Join(context.MyUsers, m => m.MemberId, u => u.Id,(m, u) => u);
        var leader = team.Leader;

        var usersList = await query.ToListAsync();
        usersList.Add(leader);
        return usersList;
    }

    public async Task AddTeam(string name, string? description, Guid leaderId)
    {
        await context.Teams.AddAsync(new Team(name,description, leaderId));
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}


Please [edit] your question to include the source code of the TeamsRepository class. Most likely an Include() is missing.

"When I create a team object", "when its loaded". It would be nice to only show the code that's relevant for those two actions, that is, a [mre]. Also, did you check the database content after "When I create a team object"? That would remove one possible culprit.

EF Core has multiple ways to load related data (described here), but it doesn't load any by default. For EF Core to automagically load the related entity when accessing a property you have to enable lazy loading and make the naviagtion virtual, as described here.
If you don't want to do that you'll have to use eager or explicit loading. Eager loading means adding .Include(x => ...) calls to your queries, and explicit loading means doing DbContext.Entry(...) in separate calls.
In your case, I'd use eager loading, adding for example .Include(x -> x.Leader) to the queries you want/ need the leader.
E.g.
public async Task<IList<Team>> GetTeams()
{
    // Notice the added '.Include(...)' call
    return await context.Teams.Include(x -> x.Leader).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
}

Calling GetTeams will now return a List of Team and they're attached Leader.

As an aside, many people consider lazy loading bad practice, while it does enhance the developer experience it can (in many cases severily) harm performance. It's also an added layer of indirection, you, as the developer, don't explicitly see where, what and when something is loaded from the database.

That makes a lot of sense now, thank you.

Don't bother with a repository like that. It is too rigid and offers absolutely nothing over the Repository EF already provides in the DbSet<Team>. Regimenting calls like that with the repository means you are left missing .Include(x => x.Leader) etc. which would ensure expected related data is loaded.
Modifiers like AsNoTracking() are recommended on read-only operations, but you really don't want to use it in all cases.
If you are doing an update you should leverage change tracking as it is intended and not use the Updatemethod on the DbContext. Update results in all columns being overwritten whether you intend/allow them to change or not. This can expose data to bugs and malicious acts. Change tracking gives control over what changes and EF will generate more efficient UPDATE SQL statements.
EF provides a lot of capability, it's a lot of work and waste to use it like a replacement for ADO.Net for regimented CRUD patterns.
